# The space of integral liftings of a variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

This question consists of two slightly similar questions.

a) Let $F$ be a field of positive characteristic. Let $X$ be a smoooth proper geometrically connected $F$-scheme.

Let $C$ be the category of local integral domains together with an isomorphism from the residue field to $F$.

Consider the (covariant?) functor from $C$ to sets, sending a ring $R$ to the set of $R$-isomorphism classes of smooth proper $R$-schemes whose special fiber, which is naturally an $F$-scheme, is isomorphic to $X$ (or take values in groupoids if it helps).

Is this (co-)representable by something geometric? What if restrict to Noetherian rings, or DVR's?

b) Let $R$ be a DVR with the residue field $F$ of positive characteristic. Consider the functor sending smooth proper geometrically connected $F$-schemes to the set of liftings to $R$-schemes as above. Is this (co-)representable by something geometric?

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  The restriction of the functor $F$ to the category of local Artin rings with residue field a finite extension of $F$ is representable, cf. Proposition 3.4 of the following: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0602646.pdf   Thus, the functor is "prorepresentable".  However, without an ample invertible sheaf as part of your setup, the prorepresenting object is rarely "effective".

Comment: Could you please register your account, and avoid asking questions on new accounts?